# Uncrustify option to leave whitespace on blank lines

Tags: uncrustify

I'm trying to find the option that leaves whitespace on blank lines. Currently uncrustify will strip all trailing whitespace (good!), however I want to keep whitespace if it's on a blank line, because it's generally to the indent level.

Is this a blank line `nl_*` option, or an indentation `indent_*` option? I can't find one to do what I want, or even to control the trailing whitespace option! It just does it by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I received a [response](https://github.com/bengardner/uncrustify/issues/132) from Ben Gardner, the project lead, who had this to say:

> There is no option to do this and there is no plan to add an option to do that at this point.