# Uncrustify: remove space opening/closing a block

Tags: c++, formatting, uncrustify

How can I clean up blocks like the following:

```
if(a)
{

   foo();

}
```

into

```
if(a)
{
   foo();
}
```

Comment: This might help: [Uncrustify option to leave whitespace on blank lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297499/uncrustify-option-to-leave-whitespace-on-blank-lines). Looks like it's not supported.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg uncrustify is the tool I'm using.

Comment: How about a regex find and replace to replace \n\n with \n then tell uncrustify where to add new lines?

Answer (score 0):

Check these options:

```
# Whether to remove blank lines after '{'
eat_blanks_after_open_brace     = true    # false/true

# Whether to remove blank lines before '}'
eat_blanks_before_close_brace   = true    # false/true
```

But some other options such as `mod_full_brace_if` and `nl_if_leave_one_liners` can also have an impact. Could convert it to `if(a) foo();` for example.